# I want to create a calendar in flutter which on zoom in changes the view from month to week, on further zoom to day and also like wise zoom out

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

Zoom in zoom out in calendar view with flutter

I try zoomable widget also interactive widget with gesturedetector widget.

Basically i want to create it in such way that on zoom in it changes the view from month to week and further to day and vice versa from day to week to month on zoom out

Comment: You can use Hero animation for that.